# Can I change vim completion preview window height?

Tags: vim, preview, code-completion

I'm using Eclimd for completion. it generates a lot of helpful info about function, but in 1-line preview window it looks messy. (same window uses by omni-completion)

So:

1. Is there any way to change default preview window height?
2. Make preview-popup instead of preview-window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am facing problems with 'previewheight' too so I came up with the following work around:

```
set previewheight=50
au BufEnter ?* call PreviewHeightWorkAround()
func PreviewHeightWorkAround()
    if &previewwindow
        exec 'setlocal winheight='.&previewheight
    endif
endfunc
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this one! Was trying out vim-fugitive and the :Gstatus was being a one liner (pretty much useless) because my winheight was set to 999.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default height of the preview window by setting the `'previewheight'` option.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, strange. Looks like it also deletes all newlines from preview-code.

Comment: you have to put this in your .vimrc file: set previewheight=5

Comment: setting previewheight in .vimrc is restricted to reducing it below 3 lines, because that is the upper limit *hardcoded in the Vim source code* (search for `g_do_tagpreview`), even though the default value of previewheight is 12. Pretty darn awkward.

Answer (score 0):

`set previewheight` didn't work for me, but `set previewwindow winheight` worked for me.