# Why does only the centerwindow split for :Gstatus?

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

*After looking at the great [vimcast-series](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/) about fugitive I have tried to use it for a while. But I have some strangeness going on. So here is one question*:

When I have a merge conflict and open the file I get the layout

```
----------------------------
|        |         |       |
| target | working | merge |
| (HEAD) |  copy   |       |
|        |         |       |
----------------------------
```

When I then try to view the status with `:Gstatus` I get:

```
----------------------------
|        | status  |       |
| target |---------| merge |
| (HEAD) | working |       |
|        |  copy   |       |
----------------------------
```

instead of the expected:

```
----------------------------
|          status          |
|--------------------------|
| target | working | merge |
| (HEAD) |  copy   |       |
----------------------------
```

What can I do to find out what’s wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The `:Gstatus` command uses the *preview window*, and that is opened (as with `:pedit`) as a plain *above split*. If you have vertical splits, the preview window will be restricted to the current window column (as you illustrate in your question).

I don't know where your expectations come from, but you could ask fugitive's maintainer to open the preview window (if it doesn't exist yet) with `:topleft pedit`, to get the behavior you want. To work around the issue, open the preview window at the right location before `:Gstatus`, or correct the layout afterwards with `:wincmd K` or `<C-w>K`.

Comment: The expectations comes from watching the vimcast-video that I linked to.

Comment: I ended up using your idea to making a map that does this for me: `nmap <leader>gs :Gstatus<cr><c-w>k<c-w>K<c-w>p`. (`:Gstatus<cr>` to open the status, `<c-w>k` to move up to the status buffer, `<c-w>K` to correct the layout, and `<c-w>p` to move back to the previous buffer). @kalbasit's solution would be more complete, but this oneline works for me since I wouldn't have any reason to type `:Gstatus` instead of a mapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
set previewheight=15
au BufEnter ?* call PreviewHeightWorkAround()
func PreviewHeightWorkAround()
  if &previewwindow
    exec 'wincmd K'
    exec 'setlocal winheight='.&previewheight
  endif
endfunc
```

This has worked for me to achieve exactly what you're looking for.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787326/301730